# How to fetch GitHub branch names using GraphQL

Tags: branch, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

Using GitHub GraphQL API (v.4) I would like to get all the branch names existing on a given repository.

My attempt

```
{
  repository(name: "my-repository", owner: "my-account") {
    ... on Ref {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

returns error:

```
{'data': None, 'errors': [{'message': "Fragment on Ref can't be spread inside Repository", 'locations': [{'line': 4, 'column': 13}]}]}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how to retrieve 10 branches from a repo:

```
{
  repository(name: "git-point", owner: "gitpoint") {
    refs(first: 10, , refPrefix:"refs/heads/") {
      nodes {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PS: You usually use spread when dealing with an Union type (like IssueTimeline for example, which is composed of different kind of objects, so you can spread on a particular object type to query specific fields.

---

You might need to use [pagination](https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/) to get all branches

Comment: Is there a way to get **all** branches of a repository instead of `first: 10`? The API gives me an error if I don't supply a `first` argument to `refs`, but how do I tell the API that I want all branches?